# Como fazer um sistema de adição de botões com eventos únicos para launch?

Tags: vb.net, button

Eu gostaria de saber como fazer um sistema em que automaticamente adiciona em um FlowLayoutPanel, para cada arquivo de uma pasta, um botão com um evento específico que, ao clicar, inicia o aplicativo.
O código que eu sei fazer é mais ou menos assim:

```
Try
        For Each file As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments)
            Dim mbtn As New MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialFlatButton
            mbtn.Icon = (Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(file)).ToBitmap
            mbtn.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(file)
            mbtn.Tag = file
            flp.Controls.Add(mbtn)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Com isso, já consegui fazer tudo, menos o sistema de abrir o link.
E também gostaria de saber como esconder a extensão.
Aguardo respostas :)

Comment: Sem resposta..... ;-;

Comment: ;-;-;-;-;-;-;-; PQ ISSO

Comment: Se este controle "MaterialFlatButton" tiver eventos, adicione um com o `AddHandler`: `AddHandler mbtn.Click, AddressOf mbtn_Click` e depois declare sua função: `Private Sub mbtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)`. Para o caso de não trazer a extenção use: `mbtn.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)`.

Comment: @ismael, seu comentário na verdade é a resposta à questão do post, creio que você deveria publicá-la como resposta...

Answer (score 2):

Você precisará criar um evento em seu controle.
Utilize o [AddHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/7taxzxka.aspx), veja:

```
AddHandler mbtn.Click, AddressOf mbtn_Click
```

Depois, declare sua função `mbtn_Click`:

```
Private Sub mbtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   ' ...seu código
End Sub
```

Sua função será executada sempre que o [evento de click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx) for acionado em seus controles.
Se quiser algo específico para determinado controle, terá que fazer um tratamento utilizando o parâmetro `sender`.

```
Private Sub mbtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Select CType(sender, MaterialFlatButton).Name
    Case "MaterialFlatButton1_Nome"
        ' seu código
    Case "MaterialFlatButton2_Nome"
        ' seu código
    End Select
End Sub
```

---

Para o caso de não trazer a extenção use:

```
mbtn.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
```